# another view with action button in navigation Bar Items

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to open a new view using a button that is in a navigationBarItems. I put my code. Thanks for your help.

```
struct ClienteView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(clientes) { cliente in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetallesClienteView(objCliente: cliente)){
                    DetallesCliente(objCliente: cliente)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Clientes"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {

                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "person.badge.plus")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this kind of thing:

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing:
    NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(), label: {
        Image(systemName: "person.badge.plus")
    })
)
```